# I'm getting an error when trying to install MongoJS. How can I fix it?

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, express, mongojs

So i have installed the latest version of `nodejs` on my PC. I'm using Git. Using Git I install Express into my directory `npm install express`. Everything is perfectly executed.

Then I try to run `npm install mongojs`, but that's when I get this errors:

[Error](http://pastebin.com/X9wqm6NP)

I've installed the latest version (3.2) of MongoDB in my `C:\mongo\` directory.

What is wrong? Why do I get these errors when I try to install MongoJS?

Comment: It says exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) does not support python 3, as you can see in the error:

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.4.3, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
```

They are also saying that in their docs.